# Connect Ids with each other in angular ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I don't know where to start, I have project saved and when I click the project this goes to head of subproject from there I wan't for each subproject I save to go to the project clicked in array of subProjectIds. Do you have any idea how to achieve this. Waiting for your responses

```
save() {
if (this.newSubProjectName.length > 0) {
  this.working = true;
  const newSubProject: SubProject = emptySubProject();
  newSubProject.name = this.newSubProjectName;
  newSubProject.id = Math.random().toString();
  newSubProject.color = this.newSubProjectColor;
  this.store.dispatch(new 
   UpsertSubProjectInternalAction(newSubProject));
  this.newSubProjectName = '';
}
}
```

Here is the Action and reducer.

```
export class UpsertSubProjectInternalAction implements Action {
static readonly Type: string = 'budcon-item: upsert-subproject-
internal';
readonly type: string = UpsertSubProjectInternalAction.Type;

constructor(public payload?: SubProject) {
}
}

function upsertSubProject(state: BudconState, action: 
 UpsertSubProjectInternalAction): BudconState {
 const subProject = action.payload;

 return {
 ...state,
 subProjectsIds: state.subProjectsIds.set(subProject.id, subProject),
};
}
```

Here is the interface of Project

```
export interface Project {
id: string;
category: string;
color: number;
name: string;
state: number;
type: number;
level: number;
select: string;
subProjectIds: string[];
}
```

You see at interface of Project it is `subProjectIds` when I save a subProject this to be the key that communicate between Project and SubProject. If you have something to ask let me know I will help for my question.

Comment: I am not seeing a question in your question.

Comment: I edited the question, but I need to connect project with subproject while when I select project shows in subproject head and then when I add a subproject must be under the Project with subProjectIds like parent.